# wordpress 3 and turbo link

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

when upgrading to Wordpress 3.01 I thought the turbo link would disappear from the dashboard, as per http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Tools_SubPanel . However, the Turbo link still shows up in the header of my dashboard after the upgrade. How do I remove the Turbo link (even if I have to edit the core files to achieve this) ?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, exactly. Custom Admin Branding plugin has the Turbo link hard coded in custom_branding.php, line 555.

I like the plugin, so just edited it to suit. I also changed the "Howdy" greeting (line 548), what with me not being a cowboy.

Answer (score 0):

it was a 'Custom Admin Branding' wordpress plugin that caused this so i am using another plugin instead.